# Is there any way to add reviews to specified attribute like manufacturer?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, review

I created an attribute called `seller` with all properties of `manufacturer`. I am showing that attribute on product view and list pages successfully. My question is: How to allow customers to write review and ratings for that `seller` attribute as like for products?
**Is these possible?**

If it is possible: How to achieve that?

Any ideas, suggestions would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, it is of course possible. But: It will be quite some work. You need to create your own module for this and write the review functionality on your own.

As you mentioned correctly: The Magento standard review functionality is product reviews and ratings only.